# Passing multiple files to an exec.Command invocation from storage buckets

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm attempting to build a cloud function written in Go, that will use the available ImageMagick library in Google's Cloud Functions infrastructure to composite & manipulate several images into a resulting output image.

The root of the problem, is that the ImageMagick function that I want to use is available, but it takes multiple distinct inputs in order to work. My inputs are objects in a Storage Bucket.

The os/exec Cmd struct allows you to do this, by using an "ExtraFiles" array, and I know how to provide these extra files to my ImageMagick command.

However, the "ExtraFiles" array only wants to store instances of os.File, whereas the GCP Storage Client gives you a "Reader" instance when you open a file.

````
        backgroundBlob := storageClient.Bucket(inputBucket).Object(background)
        backgroundImg, err := backgroundBlob.NewReader(ctx)
        if err != nil {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("backgroundImg: %v", err)
        }

        foregroundBlob := storageClient.Bucket(inputBucket).Object(foreground)
        foregroundImg, err := foregroundBlob.NewReader(ctx)
        if err != nil {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("foregroundImg: %v", err)
        }

        outputBlob := storageClient.Bucket(outputBucket).Object(output)
        outputImg := outputBlob.NewWriter(ctx)
        defer outputImg.Close()

        // Set up some additional file handles since we're dealing with more inputs than STDIN Can cope with
        cmd := exec.Command("convert", "fd:3", "fd:4", "-composite", "fd:5")
        cmd.ExtraFiles = append(cmd.ExtraFiles,backgroundImg)
        cmd.ExtraFiles = append(cmd.ExtraFiles,foregroundImg)
        cmd.ExtraFiles = append(cmd.ExtraFiles,outputImg)

        if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("cmd.Run: %v", err)
        }

        log.Printf("Blurred image has been uploaded to %s", outputBlob.ObjectName())

        return outputBlob.ObjectName(), nil
}```

So, from where I am at the moment, I need to do one of the following two things:
1. Figure out how to get Google's storage API to treat/use objects in their storage buckets as "os.File"s
OR
2. Figure out how to execute my "convert" command using multiple Readers as input, rather than leveraging the ExtraFiles array.

If anybody out there has any ideas on how to achieve either of the above, or has alternate ways of solving this problem, I would be very grateful to hear them!
````

Comment: ImageMagick generally uses `fd:N` to read pipes. Did you try [`os.Pipe`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Pipe)?

Comment: Hi @jimB, I've taken a look at the os.Pipe mechanism, but I don't think it really suits my needs. Even if I can use the Pipe to wrap the Reader object from the Storage API, I still don't seem to have a way to provide that as input to the exec.Command structure

Comment: I'm not sure how it doesn't suit your needs, `os.Pipe` returns 2 `*os.File`, and you can append the read side to `cmd.ExtraFiles` just like you do below. There's nothing wrong with caching the files locally, but a streaming solution is sometimes more efficient.

Comment: Hi @jimB - Thanks for the reply. I'm not really sure what I missed the first time around, but I completely agree that a streaming solution would be better & I should be able to use the os.Pipe mechanism to achieve this. I've re-done my overlay function to make use of the Pipes now & it's kinda functional, but the convert command now takes about 2 1/2 minutes to execute. I'm going to keep looking and I'll post an update if I figure it out.

Comment: I can't fathom it - using Pipes, the script does work, but it'll take anywhere from 1 to 5 minutes to complete, whereas using the temporary files it takes a second or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anybody who happens across this question in the future - I found a workaround. I'm not thrilled with it, but it is functional.

Essentially, I was able to slurp the contents of the storage Readers & then create my own os.File objects within the Cloud Functions context. Then, passing that os.File to the exec.Cmd invocation. It's definitely not ideal, but here's the code:

```
func Overlay(ctx context.Context, inputBucket, outputBucket, background string, foreground string, output string) (string, error) {
        // Retrieve the Background Image from the storage API
        backgroundBlob := storageClient.Bucket(inputBucket).Object(background)
        backgroundImg, err := backgroundBlob.NewReader(ctx)
        if err != nil {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("backgroundImg: %v", err)
        }        
        // Read the contents of the file into a variable
        backgroundSlurp, err := ioutil.ReadAll(backgroundImg)
        if err != nil {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("readFile: unable to read data from bucket %q, file %q: %v", inputBucket, background, err)
        }
        // Write the contents of Background Image to an os.File instance
        err = ioutil.WriteFile(fmt.Sprintf("/tmp/%s",background), backgroundSlurp, 0644)
        if err != nil {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("backgroundImg: %v", err)
        }
        // Open the os.File instance to pass it on to os.exec later
        backgroundFile, err := os.Open(fmt.Sprintf("/tmp/%s",background))
        if err != nil {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("backgroundFile: %v", err)
        }

        foregroundBlob := storageClient.Bucket(inputBucket).Object(foreground)
        foregroundImg, err := foregroundBlob.NewReader(ctx)
        if err != nil {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("foregroundImg: %v", err)
        }
        // Read the contents of the file into a variable
        foreroundSlurp, err := ioutil.ReadAll(foregroundImg)
        if err != nil {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("readFile: unable to read data from bucket %q, file %q: %v", inputBucket, foreground, err)
        }
        // Write the contents of Foreground Image to an os.File instance
        err = ioutil.WriteFile(fmt.Sprintf("/tmp/%s",foreground), foreroundSlurp, 0644)
        if err != nil {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("foregroundImg: %v", err)
        }
        // Open the os.File instance to pass it on to os.exec later
        foregroundFile, err := os.Open(fmt.Sprintf("/tmp/%s",foreground))
        if err != nil {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("foregroundFile: %v", err)
        }

        outputBlob := storageClient.Bucket(outputBucket).Object(output)
        outputImg := outputBlob.NewWriter(ctx)
        defer outputImg.Close()

        // Set up some additional file handles since we're delaqing with more inputs than STDIN Can cope with
        cmd := exec.Command("convert", "fd:3", "fd:4", "-composite", "-")
        cmd.Stdout = outputImg
        cmd.ExtraFiles = append(cmd.ExtraFiles,backgroundFile)
        cmd.ExtraFiles = append(cmd.ExtraFiles,foregroundFile)

        if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("cmd.Run: %v", err)
        }

        log.Printf("Blurred image has been uploaded to %s", outputBlob.ObjectName())

        return outputBlob.ObjectName(), nil
}
```

Comment: Hi user3644822, good work finding the solution! Can you accept your own answer? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!